# Does Create Content Type need to be a farm solution?

Tags: content-type, farm-solution, sandbox-solution

I've found a couple of examples of creating a content type using visual studio.

http://stevemannspath.blogspot.com/2010/11/sharepoint-2010-leveraging-visual.html

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff630942.aspx

They both say "Deploy as Farm Solution".

Why cant they be sand box solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to create content types with sandbox solutions

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798382.aspx

> What Can I Do with Sandboxed
>   Solutions?
>
> Create a content type: Sandbox = Tick

This may help you

http://sharepointbuzzer.wordpress.com/2010/10/21/list-definition-using-sandbox-in-sharepoint-2010/